# Spring Data Elasticsearch : detect mapping differences

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

In Spring Data Elasticsearch is there a way of detecting that the mapping on the index does not match the mapping created from the Entity object?

i.e.
I allowed Spring Data Elasticsearch to create the mapping originally from the entity model annotated with `@Document` and `@Field`

At a later point I add a new field to the model, but do not update the index mapping, this new field then won't be correctly configured until I re-index to the new mapping

So is there a way to detect such discrepancies so I will know which indexes need to have their mappings re-created, and documents re-indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but the answer is not too complicated.

Let's assume we have a `Foo` entity class to be stored in an `foo` index and a `FooRepository` that uses this class. On
application startup, when the index does not exist, it will be created with the mapping derived from the entity.

In order to detect changes in the maping derived from the class and the one stored in Elasticsearch you can use an
approach like this:

```java
@Component
public class FooMappingValidator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooMappingValidator.class);

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final ElasticsearchOperations operations;

    public FooMappingValidator(ElasticsearchOperations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void checkFooMapping() {

        var indexOperations = operations.indexOps(Foo.class);

        if (indexOperations.exists()) {
            LOGGER.info("checking if mapping for Foo changed");

            var mappingFromEntity = indexOperations.createMapping();
            var mappingFromEntityNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(mappingFromEntity);
            var mappingFromIndexNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(indexOperations.getMapping());

            if (!mappingFromEntityNode.equals(mappingFromIndexNode)) {
                LOGGER.info("mapping for class Foo changed!");
                indexOperations.putMapping(mappingFromEntity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a Spring component that has `ElasticsearchOperations` injected and that has a method that is annotated with
`@Autowired`. An autowired method is executed after all the dependencies have been injected in the beans. This means
it runs before the normal application logic is started.

In this method we first get an `IndexOperations` instance for our entity class. Next we check if the index exists,
if it doesn't, we do not need to check.

In the next step we get the current mapping from the entity and convert it to a `JsonNode` and do the same with the
mapping we retrieve from Elasticsearch. We use `JsonNode`s here because the have an `equals()` method that
does the comparison we need.

If we detect that the both mappings are different, we write the new one to the index with the `putMapping()` method.

**NOTE:**

This only works when new properties are added to the entity, as existing mappings cannot be changed in Elasticsearch,
there you'd need reindexing.

Comment: This seems to mostly work, but I have a problem with a field marked `@Field(type = FieldType.Object)` the mappingFromEntity will contain a `"type": "object"` whereas the mappingFromIndex does not, and will therefore never match.  Would a example on the Github issue tracker help?

Comment: I noted this behaviour when I started integrating the new Elasticsearch client (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/45). When a field is mapped as object, Elasticsearch does not return it's type when mappings are retrieved. It might be possible to iterate through the `mappingFromEntityTree` and remove `type` properties than have the value `object` before comparing.

Comment: Be careful with this, as a different sorting order of fields in your model changes the JSON already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that withstands changing sort orders of the model.
Note that this only really works if you annotate each model field with the actual type in ElasticSearch / OpenSearch like so:

```
@Field(type = Long)
var coldRent: Int? = null
```

If you do not specify the actual type explicitly, it is set to `Type.Auto`, which I suppose is resolved to its *actual* type only during runtime. Hence, the diff-logic cannot work (also not the above mentioned one).

Example code in Kotlin:

```
val indexOperations = elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(MyModel::class.java)

if (indexOperations.exists()) {
  val existingMapping = (indexOperations.mapping["properties"] as Map<String, *>).keys
  val mappingCandidate = (indexOperations.createMapping()["properties"] as Map<String, *>).keys

  val missingOnRemote = mappingCandidate.filter { !existingMapping.contains(it) }

  if (missingOnRemote.isNotEmpty()) {
    LOGGER.i { "Mapping is out of sync. Missing fields on remote and thus, updating mapping: $missingOnRemote" }
    indexOperations.putMapping(indexOperations.createMapping())
    indexOperations.refresh()
  } else {
    LOGGER.w { "Mapping is up to date." }
  }  
}
```

Comment: you would need some recursive descent, as mappings can contain nested objects

Comment: true, thanks for pointing out. Not a case for us but I'm sure people may find our themselves. Just wanted to share this approach - might be of help.